# Why can't I get crash logs from Apple with my Apple ID?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

My Apple ID  is a member of a developer team,and was set as Admin, Technical, App Manager, and Developer role. According to apple:

> Who can access crash logs in Xcode?
>   iTunes Connect users with the Admin, Technical, App Manager, or Developer role can access crash logs.

I should have full access to Crash logs,and I have done everything describe in [Before Viewing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html).

The problem is: When I sign in Xcode with the owner of the developer team,everything works fine. If I logout the owner's Apple Id , and login in with my own apple id, I can still receive crash logs for old release versions normally,but I can't see new release versions and receive any crash logs of new versions in the crashes view of Xcode.

I tried to logout my apple id and login multiple times,and try it with Xcode 7.3.1, Xcode 8.0 beta(8S128d),but didn't work.

Comment: How do you know there is a sufficient number of crashes to show up?

Comment: @meaning-matters  I login  with owner's apple id  in other mac, and see 300+ crash logs and a new version.but my mac login with my apple id didn't have this new version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Please contant Apple.